# Trouble installing transfixed trading package - hangs on quickfix

Tags: windows, quickfix

I am trying to access the trading protocol FIX for which there is a python packed called "transfixed"
I am running on a Windows 10 system with python 3.7

I am running the following command:

```
pip install transfixed
```

The build for transfixed works, but when the build section comes to quickfix, the following errors occur:

```
Building wheel for quickfix (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [14 lines of output]
      Testing for std::tr1::shared_ptr...
      test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp
      test_std_tr1_shared_ptr.cpp(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'tr1/memory': No such file or directory
       ...not found
      Testing for std::shared_ptr...
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'
      test_std_shared_ptr.cpp
      ...found
      Testing for std::unique_ptr...
      cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '-std=c++0x'
      test_std_unique_ptr.cpp
      ...found
      cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-deprecated'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for quickfix
  Running setup.py clean for quickfix
Successfully built transfixed
Failed to build quickfix
ERROR: Could not build wheels for quickfix, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`
```

Any help with this would be appreciated